# NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains returns different results depend on environment

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, filesystems

I' using code below to get appliction support directory:

```
NSString * supportDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

if it is executed  on iphone or simulator i get correct path (with app guid): 
a) iphone:
`/var/mobile/Applications/APP_GUID/Library/Application Support/` 
b) simulator:
`/Users/realuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/APP_GUID/Library/Application Support/`

where: 
 - realuser - my username 
 - APP_GUID - application's GUID

but when it is executed on CI server - Hudson (automatic build, but with iOS 5.1 simualtor) i got

`/Users/realuser/Library/Application Support/`

so there is no guid application string in path.

In both cases array from function: 
`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)` 
contains only one object, so ther is no dfference if it is last or first object in array.

I've make some google research but without solution. Is it somethink missing on Hudson env variables ? how can i fix it ?

Maybe is it better to use interface URLsForDirectory:inDomains: ?

--
Regards
Adam

Comment: I noticed this as well, but could not find anything stating the change in behaviour. In the Apple Core Data templates they use `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:`.

Comment: I've checked also with URLsForDirectory:inDomains:, but result is the same

Answer (score 0):

This is connected with way of executing application. On iPhone and simulator application is sandboxed, so path contains application's GUID, on CI server application is not sandboxed, so there is no application's GUID.